simulink&raspberry
I build a model in simulink ，i want to deploy into the pi。
the model is to control the motor by changing the dutycycle,but it failed .the warning is :
"No signals uploaded from the target application. Enable signal logging for model 'Simulink_Nano_Motor_Control_RTech_202208v1'. For more information, see Configure Signal Monitoring and Parameter Tuning for XCP External Mode.
组件:Simulink | 类别:Block diagram 警告
Saving external mode simulation output as a single object is not supported because the workspace variable 'out'  is not created during model code execution. To suppress the warning, set 'ReturnWorkspaceOutputs' to 'off'.
I run directly in the pi ,it shows "can't lock /var/run/pigpio.pid"
how can i fix this.my version is 4B ,the os is downloaded through the matlab,all the pin number is correct.

Error "can't lock /var/run/pigpio.pid" typically occurs when another process is already using the pigpio library on your Raspberry Pi.

i do the killall it says pigpiod：no process found
